# Imported module not available when using remote WSL (Win10 -> Ubuntu)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pylance

I have used this tutorial to setup remote development in WSL: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial

All works well until I want to load a .py file that imports an external modal.
E.g. I've cloned this repo: https://github.com/AI4Finance-Foundation/FinRL_Podracer/

I can run it successfully using command line.

But when trying to debug I get an error:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'gym'

[image]

Visual Studio Code also shows an error when hovering over it:

[image: import module error]

I've obviously tried to run `pip install gym` in the WSL console. But that doesn't seem to register.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating an environment instead of using the global environment. Activate that environment and install gym in it. Then try setting your python interpreter in VSCode to run your python file in:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment